# Joomla editor field error - HTML removed on saving

Tags: php, iframe, joomla, joomla-extensions

I am developing a custom Joomla module using Joomla 3.4 (latest version). I want to add a Joomla editor field, which I did. but when I save, it stripes all html tag, including iframes. What am I doing wrong here?

Please not that am using JCE editor and I have enabled embedding iframe option.

**My XML:**

```
< field name="map" type="editor" label="Map"  width="300"  />
```

**My PHP:**

```
$map = $params->def('map');
<div><?php echo $map; ?></div
```

Answer (score 3):

I simpy add this attribute in xml field

```
filter="raw"
```